# Using an event with an associated timestamp to select all dates between the event and today

Tags: powerbi, dax

I currently have a [Calendar Table] with all dates on it. 
I also have an [Activities Table] with associated timestamps as well as an [Events Table] with associated timestamps.

I would like to be able to select an event from the [Events Table] from a slicer, and then see all activities from the [Activities Table] that occurred SINCE that event. Currently I'm having trouble doing this since if I relate everything (two way) to the [Calendar Table], my result will just be the activities that occurred on the same day as the event, not SINCE it.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to make a separate [Entity Table] for the attendees and then make a relationship between the [Events Table] and that. A simple function then gave me what I needed:

```
Scheduled Date = max('Events Table'[Date])
```

```
Total Category Activities After = CALCULATE([Activities], filter('Calendar Table', 'Calendar Table'[Date] > [Scheduled Date]))
```